# In progress wheel in Dojo

Tags: dojo

Is there a "in progress" wheel as a dojo/dijit widget?

My json request takes quite some time and I should show the user that something is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your request ? A dojo.xhr call ? You should read this : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/promises/

Comment: try: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/ProgressBar. Also see: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html - open the "Popups and Alerts" accordion pane and see the "slow loading modal dialog" example - that is much closer to what you want

Comment: I have added <span class="dojoxGridLoading">Loading...</span> as you mentioned in a comment below. What did you add to remove it when your request is finished?

Comment: Not sure; I think I just removed it by an id after a ajax request finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the StandBy widget to do this.  The following snippet shows how.  The code is a bit old and doesn't use the deferred technique that Philippe mentioned, but you could easily do so.

```
var url = ...

var xhrArgs = {
    url: url,
    handleAs: "text",
    load: dojo.hitch(this, function(data) {

      this._standby.hide();

      ... do work ...                   

    }),
    error: dojo.hitch(this, function(error){
      this._standby.hide();
      throw error;
    })
};

if (!this._standby) {
    this._standby = new dojox.widget.Standby({
      target: this.domNode
    });
    dojo.body().appendChild(this._standby.domNode);
}

this._standby.show();
dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks, I might use the Standby object later, I use for the moment a span tag with the class declaration of the "standby" image: <span class="dojoxGridLoading">Loading...</span>