# Dojo hiding and showing div using Attach points

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a loader div defined as say for simplicity

```
<div dojoAttachpoint="loaderDiv" style="display:none;">.....</div>
```

Now when i have a function that is called i want this div to be shown, how do i do that ?

Comment: why are you using dojoAttachpoint? youcan do it easily only with id, or even add some cool dojo effects like http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fx/wipeIn-examples.html

Comment: I think you will have to access a widget first and then change its content. Maybe you can find some help in this tutorial, because the result is widget that changes style of its components when you click them... http://mindtrove.info/creating-an-accessible-internationalized-dojo-rating-widget/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojoAttachPoint`s are used in widget templates.  So in your widget you simply refer to the node like `this.loaderDiv`

```
dojo.style(this.loaderDiv, 'display', '');
```

If this code is not in a widget, then you should be using id.

```
<div id="loaderDiv" style="display:none;">.....</div>

dojo.style(dojo.byId('loaderDiv'), 'display', '');
```

I would also recommend taking a look at the `dojox.widget.StandBy`.

[In progress wheel in Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783712/in-progress-wheel-in-dojo)

Comment: These days, use domStyle.set wherever you see dojo.style, from 'dojo/dom-style'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention this is in a custom widget you wrote, the suggested way of doing this is to expose a function from your widget that does this

You can access the loaderDiv in that function by using this.loaderDiv as Craig mentioned

It is not advised to access the loaderDiv directly from outside the widget since it is encapsulated in the widget rendering